# Mongoose creating a regular expression and searching in model for blog

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I want to implement searching in my blog so far what I have done is created a blog having search form which takes a string as input and make get request.

Now in that request I have a function which gets called for searching the string in my blog head or body.

So if a user types "foo bar" I get my results that have "foo bar"

But what I want is that this function searches for each space separated word and AND the result. i.e. search for "foo", search for "bar" and intersect the results to get
posts having "bar foo", "foo hello bar", "bar hello foo"

```
function(searchQuery, callback){
    var query = { 
        $or:[
                { head: {$regex: searchQuery, $options: "i"} },
                { body: {$regex: searchQuery, $options: "i"} } 
            ]
    };
    Post.find(query, {sort: { date: -1 }, page: i, limit: 5 }, callback);
}
```

the url of get requests is as follows

```
localhost:5000/blog/?searchQuery=FOO+BAR
```

If there is some other way around of doing this I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!
needed to create my head and body a textindex
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

and the use this code inside the function

```
function(searchQuery, callback){

    var queryString = '\"' + searchQuery.split(' ').join('\" \"') + '\"';
    var query = { $text: { $search: queryString } };
    Post.find(query, {sort: { date: -1 }, page: i, limit: 5 }, callback);

}
```

no need of regular expression!